# Get rid of the power and accessibility options on Windows 8 logon screen

Tags: windows-8, login, accessibility, login-screen

I'm using Windows 8 and I find the power button and the accessibility options very annoying. It's a computer that is in a public place surrounded with kids and they keep on changing the accessibility options and turn off the computer.

Is there a way to remove those two features from the logon screen and make it available for authenticated users only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To remove the shutdown button:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> Key, type `gpedit.msc`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In the *Local Group Policy Editor*, open *Computer Configuration – Windows Settings – Security Settings – Local Policies – Security Options*.
- Find *Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on*, double click it and select *disabled* – now the shutdown button will be gone.

To remove the Ease of Access button:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and search for `cmd`.
- Right click the *Command Prompt* result and select *Run as administrator* (click *Yes* when prompted).
- Enter this command to forbid everyone to execute `utilman.exe`:

  > `cacls %windir%\system32\utilman.exe /C /D Everyone`
- Type `Y` when you're prompted.

Should you be getting an *Access Denied* error, change the ownership of `System32\Utilman.exe` to `Administrators` (type `explorer .` in the command to open browser in current location), then try running the command again.

You can also take ownership on the command line:

```
 takeown.exe /A /F Utilman.exe
```

For Windows Home versions without Group Policy Editor, you can try the following, run `regedit.exe` as administrator and find or add the following `REG_DWORD` value:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ShutdownWithoutLogon
```

a value of `1` means `enabled`, a value of `0` means `disabled`.

If the value `ShutdownWithoutLogon` is not there, just add it as a `DWord 32-Bit` value.

Comment: they edited your answer and removed the last line that actually answers the question.

Comment: @Shimmy I paraphrased the instructions from the site Peter was linking to. We no longer allow links to it, since it's been spamming Super User quite heavily, and we don't want to feed any further traffic there. Hope you understand.

Comment: This also works for Windows 10.

Comment: Take ownership without Explorer: takeown.exe /A /F Utilman.exe

Comment: `gpedit.msc` is unavailable in home version. Any way around it, without installing external software?

Comment: @Shimmy - I added the registry change for the shutdown button.

Comment: @Shimmy There's a registry key for it which will likely need to be edited.  I thought I had a bookmark that key was saved in, but I was wrong.  Try googling something like: _"Windows" AND "registry" AND "lockscreen"_

Comment: @PeterHahndorf, thanks, the registry key did that.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I benefit your answer to this day, great answer, thank you Peter, you're awesome!

Comment: You must change `Everyone` to the localized name of this group on non-English versions (e.g. `Todos` in Spanish). Anyway, you only need to deny access to `SYSTEM`. This way, the button doesn't work in lock screen but it does for users.

Comment: Hi, this answer is great, I'd also like to remove the network flight mode button.

Comment: Found answer [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/remove-network-icon-from-windows-10-8-login-screen/).