# Windows Spotlight: Lockscreen image does not change

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903, windows-10-v1909, windows-10-v2004, windows-spotlight

Can't reproduce but since last few weeks, Windows Spotlight has been stuck on the same image. It used to work, but it's gone for a while now, not sure what I've done to break it.

Here's what I've tried:

- [Resetting and re-registering Windows Spotlight](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/82156-reset-re-register-windows-spotlight-windows-10-a.html):
- Tried deleting contents in `%USERPROFILE%/AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings`.
- Ran the following PowerShell script: `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage *ContentDeliveryManager*).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"`
- Updated Windows to latest build (version 1909, build 18363.476)
- Tried locking Windows from a new personal account

[Here](https://aka.ms/AAac1p7)'s the issue on Feedback Hub, please vote.

Comment: That's a shame; I quite like the daily slideshow of landscape pictures. Hope you can get this working sometime!

Comment: No one found a fix for this?!? I am facing the exact same in issue, also in Win10 build 1909.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It manifested itself right after I locked down a bunch of privacy settings so I suspect that there's some privacy setting that prevents Spotlight from functioning properly but I have no idea what setting it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The standard fix for stuck Spotlight image is:

- Disable Spotlight in *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*,
  by setting "Background" to Picture or Slideshow
- To delete the stuck image use Explorer to navigate to the folder

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
  ```
- Select all the files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to clear the old images
- Navigate now to the folder

  ```
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings
  ```
- Rename the files `settings.dat` and `roaming.lock` by appending `.bak` to the names
  (just in case)
- Reboot
- Enable Spotlight in *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*,
  setting "Background" to Windows Spotlight
- If everything is working correctly, delete the `.bak` files.

Comment: Have you read my question? I clearly stated this solution in my question. This did not work.

Comment: Try running `chkdsk` and [/sfc scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), then repeating the above.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` resulted in this message: _Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag._ 
[Here](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/071a55822765ca0fe048e341f71e586e#file-cbs-log)'s the contents of that file.

Comment: Seems like the reason that the Spotlight fix isn't working is some corruption that the update to Windows version 1909 didn't fix. Try re-doing it by an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which is the same as doing a Windows upgrade, so taking the same precautions.

Comment: Last installation was from an _.iso_. One thing to note, is that I performed [these](https://superuser.com/a/633136/9825) actions after the installation. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I suggest after the In-place Upgrade to test if Spotlight is now working, before doing these. Another `/sfc scannow` would also be a good idea.

Comment: Eventho I'm still getting the same error from `/sfc scannow` problem is gone now!

Comment: If everything is working fine now : "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: It worked for a couple of days, but the nasty picture is back again and stuck like before!

Comment: There is no other solution than fixing the errors. Post CBS.log again, although it's pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Made a fresh one, deleted the old logs before: [CBS.log](http://bit.ly/2DlACPj).

Comment: Try [SFCFix](https://www.sysnative.com/forums/downloads/sfcfix/). As backup, create at least a System Restore point before starting. I remark that the errors are caused by serious manipulations of Windows, such as taking ownership of crucial Windows folders and replacing `Utilman.exe` (which is a known hack for lost admin password).

Comment: Lol. The tool crashed. "_Something has gone horribly wrong and SFCFix has crashed._". Tried restarting but it still crashed.

Comment: The tool might not be up to date with the latest Windows version, or that this is also caused by the ownership changes. You could try another In-place Upgrade, but if it doesn't help then your options are either to live with the problem or reinstall Windows from scratch. I'm sorry, but I don't know of another way to undo such manipulations.

Comment: That's what does in a way the In-place Upgrade, but it doesn't fix everything.

Comment: In the future, for safely taking ownership of Windows folders, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1365110/8672) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been enjoying the Spotlight lock screen on Windows 10 and I had thought that a Windows update in November 2020 had caused Spotlight to stop updating its pictures as well as the *Like what you see?* feature to disappear from the lock screen.

I also tried all suggested solutions of the OP but unlike the OP what did work was trying Spotlight on the lock screen of a pre-existing but rarely used local account where it happened to be working perfectly from when I first logged in.
Based on [Reset Windows Spotlight](https://superuser.com/questions/1043501/reset-windows-spotlight) I originally thought that this was due to registry settings in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen* and suggested a solution based on replacing this registry path.

However, after further testing I have discovered that it was in fact changing the Windows Region from *United Kingdom* to another European country which stopped Spotlight from working. After some brief research there appear to be certain regions where Spotlight is not supported such as *Ukraine* as documented [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-windows-spotlight-doesnt-work-for-region/0f985018-6c56-4b3f-a604-2f9f36965faf).

So if you've recently changed the Windows Region and Spotlight stopped working then the following may fix the problem:

1. Disable Spotlight in *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen*, by setting *Background* to *Picture* or *Slideshow*.
2. Performing steps 4 through 6 of [How to Reset and Re-register Windows Spotlight in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/82156-reset-re-register-windows-spotlight-windows-10-a.html) to reset the Lock Screen settings and delete downloaded assets (the OP also documents the manual method of doing this).
3. Change *Settings > Region > Country or region*, to the value which was originally working with Spotlight, which for me was *United Kingdom*.
4. Re-enable Spotlight in *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen* by setting *Background* to *Windows spotlight*.
5. Wait a while (for me about 10 minutes) after which Spotlight will update the lock screen, which I actually saw happen in the *Settings > Personalization > Lock screen* window, but you can obviously also check the lock screen itself by locking the screen using the *Win + L* keyboard shortcut.
6. If you're impatient, restarting Windows might avoid this wait wait I expect.

I did also experiment with using *Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Copy settings* to set the *Welcome screen and system accounts* Location to match my *Current user* location (after setting that using *Settings > Region > Country or region* to my preferred non-*United Kingdom* region) but after a while Spotlight again stopped working with this preferred region.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Apologies @ShimmyWeitzhandler but I realised I had also reverted my Windows Region when I tested the registry replacement fix I suggested earlier. After restoring my original registry and using the non-UK region I realised that the registry replacement was not the real solution, and reverting Region to the UK was in fact the real fix, for me at least!

Comment: This bug is so inherent in Windows. I've been facing it for a nice few years. None of the solutions ever worked.